# Proper Way to Escape Quotes in HTML string that includes PHP variables

Tags: php, html, string, variables, escaping

I'm writing a string of HTML that needs to take in some of my PHP variables.  However, I can't seem to escape the double quotes correctly.

**Attempt 1:**

```
$html .= '<span class="badge"><a href="#" style="color:orange"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sendToProduction(\''.$configType.'\')"></span></a></span>';
```

**Result:**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sendToProduction(\' project\')"=""></span>
```

---

**Attempt 2:**

```
$html .= '<span class="badge"><a href="#" style="color:orange"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sendToProduction('.'$configType'.')"></span></a></span>';
```

**Result:**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sendToProduction(project)"></span>
```

Close, but should be `'project'`.

---

**Desired Result:**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sendToProduction('project')"></span>
```

Comment: Weird, your first attempt worked when I tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it comes, you were just one step closer with first try, you just need to move double quotes out of single ones.

```
$html .= '<span class="badge"><a href="#" style="color:orange"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sendToProduction("'.$configType.'")"></span></a></span>';
```

[Here you can see a live sample](http://codepad.org/8F7Kd3Tt)

Comment: Hehehe yeah you were almoust there

Answer (score 1):

[HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
$HTML = <<<_E_
<span class="badge"><a href="#" style="color:orange"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sendToProduction("$configType")"></span></a></span>
_E_;
```

Expert mode with [NOWDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) and [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$frame = <<<'_E_'
<span class="badge"><a href="#" style="color:orange"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sendToProduction("%s")"></span></a></span>
_E_;
$HTML = sprintf($frame, $configType);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend not echoing HTML, so instead do this

```
<?php
$configType = 'project';
// etc ...
?>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sendToProduction(<?= $configType ?>)"></span>
```

If you stop PHP you can write HTML and it will work normally. Inside HTML you can use short hand php echos to get whatever data you need into the HTML

One major advantage of doing this is that your editor will correctly syntax highlight all the code (including the HTML)

Answer (score 0):

You could save yourself some headaches by letting PHP do the work of variable interpolation. Place double quotes on the ends of your string and change the others to single quotes with no concatenation:

```
$html .= "<span class='badge'><a href='#' style='color:orange'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up' aria-hidden='true' onclick='sendToProduction('$configType')'></span></a></span>";
```